# Open pdf in default app using pdfmake

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic3, pdfmake

I am able to create pdf in my ionic app and if I run the app in chrome it opens perfectly. However if I install my app on the android device it doesn't open. Below is my code. Can someone please help me if I have to do something extra to open it on device. I want to open it with default pdf application on device.

```
pdfMake.createPdf(dd).open();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. After banging my head on wall for 3 days I finally found the solution and sharing here so that other people who are facing this issue can get help. I am creating pdf and saving it using cordova file plugin. After successful save I am opening it in default application using cordova file opener plugin. Below is my code.

```js
    pdfMake.createPdf(YOUR_DEFINITION_HERE).getBlob(buffer => {
      this.file.resolveDirectoryUrl(this.file.externalRootDirectory)
       .then(dirEntry => {
          this.file.getFile(dirEntry, 'test1.pdf', { create: true })
            .then(fileEntry => {
              fileEntry.createWriter(writer => {
                writer.onwrite = () => {
                  this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.toURL(), 'application/pdf')
                    .then(res => { })
                    .catch(err => {
                      const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ message: 
    err.message, buttons: ['Ok'] });
                      alert.present();
                    });
                }
                writer.write(buffer);
              })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ message: err, buttons: ['Ok'] });
              alert.present();
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ message: err, buttons: ['Ok'] 
    });
          alert.present();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you.With the answer i'm able to create a pdf in my ionic2 app.But is it possible to display the pdf without creating the file.Because in my app i have an option to preview the pdf so i dont need to save the file.I tried by modifying your code as per my requirements like after creating and opening the file i tried to delete the file but i couldnot succeed as it is throwing error which tells file is not present.can you please suggest me an approach to view pdf in ionic2 app without saving it

Comment: @abhilashreddy I am not sure if that is possible but I will try and let you know.